# MYSQL utf8 collation on date,datetime,int

Tags: php, mysql

While altering my column, I got the following error

```
ALTER TABLE mytab MODIFY mydate date CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

> 1:05:00 ALTER mytab TABLE MODIFY mydate Date CHARACTER SET utf8
>   COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci Error Code: 1064. Syntax error near 'CHARACTER
>   SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1 0.000 sec

Please help. The same thing is happening with the datatypes `int` and `datetime`.

Comment: CHARACTER SET is for strings. You can't set collations for dates and integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify a character set for CHAR, VARCHAR and TEXT columns.

Comment: thanks. So in the case of int, date  column how can we change the collation?

Comment: You can't set collation on a int or date column. Collation affects string sorting. It doesn't have any effect on numeric data types.